# Show that $A^o$ is convex, balanced, closed in $A'$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $E$ is a normed space and $A \subset E$. Define
$$A^o := \{y \in A': |y(x)| \leq 1, \forall x \in A\}.$$
in which, $A'$ is the dual space of $A$.

With this definition, how to show that $A^o$ is convex, balanced, closed in $A'$?

Comment: Are you using the weak-$\ast$ of the norm topology on $A'$? In any case, each of these properties follows pretty immediately from the definitions. Have you tried to prove it yourself?

Comment: $\forall y_1,y_2 \in A^o; \forall \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{K}, |\alpha| + |\beta| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 \in A$ i.e $\forall x \in A, |(\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2)(x)| = |\alpha y_1 (x) + \beta y_2 (x)| \le |\alpha||y_1 (x)| + |\beta||y_2 (x)| \le |\alpha|.1 + |\beta|.1 \le 1$.

$\Rightarrow \sup_{x \in A} (\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2) \le 1 \Rightarrow \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 \in A^o$. 

So, $A^o$ is convex, balanced. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you! I have proved it.